# ClassCircularityError with no apparent reason (preventing recursive classloading)

Tags: java, classloader

Interesting problem have happened several days ago. We have found workaround, but the reasons are unclear.

We have in-house distributed log tracer, which allows us to gather logs in realtime from out distributed system. Tracer implemented as a logback extension. While deploying new version we've catch `ClassCircularityError`:

```
java.lang.ClassCircularityError: ch/qos/logback/core/spi/FilterReply
    at me.bazhenov.whisperer.ActivatingTurboFilter.decide(ActivatingTurboFilter.java:33)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.TurboFilterList.getTurboFilterChainDecision(TurboFilterList.java:62)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.getTurboFilterChainDecision_0_3OrMore(LoggerContext.java:252)
```

It's intresting, because `FilterReply` is enum and have no any parents other than `java.util.Enum`. So, I don't see any possibility for `ClassCircularityError`.

While trying to debug this error, we run out web-application in development environment with different version of Jetty. And surprisingly, got (pay attention to the lines marker as `*`):

```
Exception in thread "Scanner-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:242)
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java:819)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1245)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:212)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:365)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.findClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:417)
*   at me.bazhenov.whisperer.ActivatingTurboFilter.decide(ActivatingTurboFilter.java:32)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.TurboFilterList.getTurboFilterChainDecision(TurboFilterList.java:62)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.getTurboFilterChainDecision_0_3OrMore(LoggerContext.java:252)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callTurboFilters(Logger.java:772)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.isDebugEnabled(Logger.java:490)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.isDebugEnabled(Logger.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger.isDebugEnabled(JettyAwareLogger.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog.isDebugEnabled(Slf4jLog.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:417)
*   at me.bazhenov.whisperer.ActivatingTurboFilter.decide(ActivatingTurboFilter.java:32)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.TurboFilterList.getTurboFilterChainDecision(TurboFilterList.java:62)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.getTurboFilterChainDecision_0_3OrMore(LoggerContext.java:252)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callTurboFilters(Logger.java:772)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.isDebugEnabled(Logger.java:490)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.isDebugEnabled(Logger.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger.isDebugEnabled(JettyAwareLogger.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog.isDebugEnabled(Slf4jLog.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:417)
*   at me.bazhenov.whisperer.ActivatingTurboFilter.decide(ActivatingTurboFilter.java:32)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.TurboFilterList.getTurboFilterChainDecision(TurboFilterList.java:62)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.getTurboFilterChainDecision_0_3OrMore(LoggerContext.java:252)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callTurboFilters(Logger.java:772)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.isDebugEnabled(Logger.java:490)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.isDebugEnabled(Logger.java:486)
    [...]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger.isDebugEnabled(JettyAwareLogger.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog.isDebugEnabled(Slf4jLog.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:417)
```

`ActivatingTurboFilter.java:32` has following code:

```
String value = MDC.get(key)
```

It seems like recursive class loading issue. One of the classloaders do logging, so control flow is got back in `ActivatingTurboFilter`, because we extend Logback with our custom filters and appenders. But required class still wasn't loaded, so loop closes.

We were able to workaround this problem by adding static initializer in `ActivatingTurboFilter`:

```
static {
  MDC.get("foo")
}
```

This effectively loads all required classes on the phase of loading `ActivatingTurboFilter` itself rather than moment when `ActivatingTurboFilter` methods are called.

But the question is still open. *Does Java allow this type of "recursive class loading", and if so why this problem has manifested itself?*